# Android list view show data according to the name when spinner selected an item with same name

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

```
public class AddMark extends AppCompatActivity {

SQLControlerSubject dbconnection;
Spinner spinnerM;
TextView tv_markId, tv_markSub,tv_markType;
TextView tv_listmarkId,tv_listmarkName,tv_listmarkMark,tv_listmarkType,tv_listmarkDescription;
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_mark);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddMark);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (spinnerM.getSelectedItem() != null) {

                    tv_markId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mark_id);
                    tv_markSub = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.markSub);
                    tv_markType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mark_tutorlec);

                    String markId = tv_markId.getText().toString();
                    String markSub = tv_markSub.getText().toString();
                    String markType = tv_markType.getText().toString();

                    Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddMarkInside.class);
                    modify_intent.putExtra("markId", markId);
                    modify_intent.putExtra("markSub", markSub);
                    modify_intent.putExtra("markType", markType);

                    startActivity(modify_intent);
                }
                else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select a subject", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


    // **************************Spinner view*****************************

    dbconnection = new SQLControlerSubject(this);
    dbconnection.openDatabase();
    spinnerM = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerMark);
    Cursor cursor = dbconnection.readSubjectMark();

    String[] from = new String[] {
            DBhelperSubject.SUBJECT_ID,
            DBhelperSubject.SUBJECT_NAME,
            DBhelperSubject.SUBJECT_TYPE
    };
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.mark_id,
            R.id.markSub,
            R.id.mark_tutorlec
    };

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapterMark = new SimpleCursorAdapter
                (AddMark.this, R.layout.row_format_mark, cursor, from, to);
        adapterMark.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spinnerM.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(adapterMark, R.layout.spinner_show_nothing, this));




    //**********************************List View*******************************
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMark);
        Cursor cursorM = dbconnection.readMark();

        String[] a = new String[]{
                DBhelperSubject.MARK_ID,
                DBhelperSubject.SUBJECT_NAME,
                DBhelperSubject.SUBJECT_TYPE,
                DBhelperSubject.MARK_MARKS,
                DBhelperSubject.MARK_DESCRIPTION
        };

        int[] b = new int[]{
                R.id.list_mark_id,
                R.id.list_mark_name,
                R.id.list_mark_type,
                R.id.list_mark_mark,
                R.id.list_mark_description
        };

        final SimpleCursorAdapter adapterM = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                AddMark.this, R.layout.row_format_list_mark, cursorM, a, b);

        adapterM.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.setAdapter(adapterM);

 //*******************************************************************************

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                tv_listmarkId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_mark_id);
                tv_listmarkName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_mark_name);
                tv_listmarkType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_mark_type);
                tv_listmarkMark = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_mark_mark);
                tv_listmarkDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_mark_description);


                String listmarkId = tv_listmarkId.getText().toString();
                String listmarkName = tv_listmarkName.getText().toString();
                String listmarkType = tv_listmarkType.getText().toString();
                String listmarkMark = tv_listmarkMark.getText().toString();
                String listmarkDescription = tv_listmarkDescription.getText().toString();


                Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateMark.class);
                modify_intent.putExtra("listmarkId", listmarkId);
                modify_intent.putExtra("listmarkName", listmarkName);
                modify_intent.putExtra("listmarkType", listmarkType);
                modify_intent.putExtra("listmarkMark", listmarkMark);
                modify_intent.putExtra("listmarkDescription", listmarkDescription);
                startActivity(modify_intent);
            }
        });


    }


}
```

If i use if(spinnerM.getSelectedItem() != null) on listview it will force to close.

If i want to let user to select a subject, the listview will show the subject's data only, other data which is not selected by the user will not show it out.

Comment: You haven't explain what error you want to fix clearly enough. When user selects an item the application crash? What error?

Comment: If i go to this AddMark layout it crash when i'm using if(spinnerM.getSelectedItem() != null) on list view. And the second question is how to let user to select a subject, the list view will show the subject's data only, other data which is not selected by the user will not show it out.